# Image show in full size when click

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, kendo-mobile

I am using **kendo mobile** with `cordova plugins` to build my application.

I have scenario that  I need to show the user that his/her profile image in full screen when clicked on user Profile picture.

Please suggest me if any `plugin` is available or if there any information that might help me,I am storing image in database as `base64 format`.

I am using `Knockout js to bind image in Base64 format`

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. In this case you were lucky someone answered, but without showing what you have tried, you run a real risk of having your question voted down and closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't wanna use any plugins, yes, you can use the simple [jQuery Modal Window](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial) technique by Queness. Use almost the same code, and do these changes.

```
<a class="image-thumb" href="image.jpg">
    <img src="image-thumb.jpg" alt="Image" />
</a>
```

And in the code, you can change this way:

```
$('a.image-thumb').click(function(e) {
```

Further changes for making the image to be displayed in the modal window, you can do something like this:

```
<div id="dialog" class="window">
    <img src="" alt="Image" />
</div>
```

And you need to replace that using the JavaScript! Instead of:

```
$(id).fadeIn(2000);
```

Use this way:

```
$(".window").find("img").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
$(".window").fadeIn(2000);
```

There you go! :)

Comment: @thanks,its for single click pic,if in case i have list of friends  bind with contacts with profile pic  den how i can use it dynamically

Comment: Then you have to dynamically bind some unique data attribute and show it as well.

Comment: thanks,is there any example of it,or any documentation it might help me

Comment: @adikittyCB You can use light box plugin for that, it's a popular plugin, that will easy for you. i am just gven below the link:
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: @adikittyCB If you helped from this answer please up vote the answer so that others can also get little help and tick the answer.